# How can I pass objects between dialogs in the Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I'm trying to pass an object of type `IList<Attachment>` between two Dialogs in the Bot Framework. Here's how my code looks right now:

The main dialog:

```
[Serializable]
public class CarouselCardsDialog : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        //This object, 'attachments' is what I need to pass to the child dialog.
        IList<Attachment> attachments = GetCardsAttachments();
        context.Call(new CarouselDialog(attachments), ResumeAfterPrompt);
    }

    private async Task ResumeAfterPrompt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<string> result)
    {
        string input = await result;
        await context.PostAsync(input);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private static IList<Attachment> GetCardsAttachments()
    {
        //Get a list of attachment
    }
}
```

This is the child dialog. I want to pass the list of attachments from the CarouselCardsDialog to this object:

```
[Serializable]
public class CarouselDialog : IDialog<string>
{
    private IList<Attachment> _attachments;

    public CarouselDialog(IList<Attachment> attachments)
    {
        _attachments = attachments;
    }

    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        IMessageActivity reply = context.MakeMessage();
        reply.AttachmentLayout = AttachmentLayoutTypes.Carousel;
        reply.Attachments = _attachments;
        await context.PostAsync(reply);
        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        IMessageActivity activity = await result;
        context.Done(activity.Text);
    }
}
```

However when I run this code I get this error:

> Exception: Type 'Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Attachment' in Assembly
>   'Microsoft.Bot.Connector, Version=3.5.1.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is not marked as serializable.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way around this?

Comment: error message makes it sound like your 'Attachment' class need to be [Serializable], otherwise the classes that depend on it wont be either.

Comment: @CSmith Thank you for the input. The problem is that the Attachment class belongs to the framework, so I don't think it is practical to change it. Do you know if there is an workaround to something like this?

Comment: You can create your own class, mark it as serializable and fill it with the values you are interested from the Attachment class..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not sure about the exception but a workaround would be to create a model for all the data you need to make the Attachments and then saving this data in the UserData property of your context.

```
context.UserData.SetValue<MyModel>("AttachmentsModel", instanceOfModel);
```

and then retrieving this model in your second dialog

```
MyModel model;
context.UserData.TryGetValue<MyModel>("AttachmentsModel", out model);
```

I think you can also try to place an IAttachment object in this property but a model would be better since it's not really made to hold large objects.